# Java Generics Usage for List Type

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way to use Java Generics here so my method could take a `List<Double>` or `List<Pair<Double, Double>>`?

```
private Map<Integer, Double> getValuesMap(int indexBegin, int indexEnd, List<Double> values) {
  Map<Integer, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

  if (indexBegin <= indexEnd) {
    for (int i = indexBegin; i <= indexEnd; i++) {
      map.put(i, values.get(i));
    }
  } else {
    for (int i = indexBegin; i >= indexEnd; i--) {
      map.put(i, values.get(i));
    }
  }

  return map;
}
```

Comment: How would you like this `List<Pair<Double, Double>>` to be handled if it was passed as argument? What should be expected result? Should it be `Map<Integer, Pair<Double, Double>>` OR `Map<Integer, Double>` (if yes, then which Double value from `Pair<Double, Double>` should be used here) OR maybe something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add generic to your class and use it as below,

```
public class Test<T> {
private Map<Integer, T> getValuesMap(int indexBegin, int indexEnd, List<T> values) {
        Map<Integer, T> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        if (indexBegin <= indexEnd) {
            for (int i = indexBegin; i <= indexEnd; i++) {
                map.put(i, values.get(i));
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = indexBegin; i >= indexEnd; i--) {
                map.put(i, values.get(i));
            }
        }

        return map;
    }

}
```

Update:
You could also use method generic as,

```
private <T>  Map<Integer, T> getValuesMap(int indexBegin, int indexEnd, List<T> values)
```